# I am making a game with python in pygame. I keep getting this error when I try to load my picture: "argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str"

Tags: python, pygame

How do I fix my code?

```
image = "r'Applications\\SCHOOL\\ComputerScience\\GAMESUMMATIVE\\galaxyy.jpg"
galaxyPic = pygame.image.load("galaxyy.jpg")   
screen.blit("r'Applications\\SCHOOL\\ComputerScience\\GAMESUMMATIVE\\galaxyy.jpg")
```

Comment: you need to use a surface object as the first argument in blit. you used a path to a photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
image = pygame.image.load("galaxyy.jpg")

screen.blit(image, (whatever coords you want))
```